# How convert from Option[Seq[A]] to List[A] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this class:

```
case class MyClass(field1: Option[Seq[String]],
                   field2: Option[Seq[String]],
                   field3: Option[Seq[String]])
```

and I need to translate/parse those fields into another structure of type `List[String]` .

Already tried with `map.(x => x.toString())` and `flatten`, but no donuts so far.

This snippet:

`Option[Seq[String]].toList.flatten.distinct` gives me `List[Any]`.

Comment: Are you sure? If I define `val s = Option(Seq("tr", "tr"))` and than `s.toList.flatten.distinct`, I get `res0: List[String] = List(tr)`

Comment: You want to merge all field into one `List[String]` or each one, separately` to a `List[String]`? and why do you call `.distinct`? Do you have a requirement for the output elements to be distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find similar statements in various places such as this one from [Idiomatic Scala: Your Options Do Not Match](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/06/15/idiomatic-scala-your-options-do-not-match/):

> The most idiomatic way to use an scala.Option instance is to treat it as a collection or monad and use map, flatMap, filter, or foreach […] A less-idiomatic way to use scala.Option values is via pattern matching

That page offers an example of `fold` which might be used like this to give a List[String]:

```
field.fold(List[String]())(_.toList)
```

As suggested by @Evgeny, this also results in a List[String]:

```
field.toList.flatten.distinct
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I think you could do it using getOrElse (and toList if you're not happy with a Seq):

```
// Seq[String]
field.getOrElse(List.empty)

// List[String]
field.getOrElse(List.empty).toList
```

I'm assuming you could use an empty List if a field is `None`. Hope that helps!